# jquery clone issue, modifying id changes original selector too

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-clone

In this code example

```
var attachmentDeletePhotoModal = $('#attachment-deletion');
attachmentDeletePhotoModal.clone();
attachmentDeletePhotoModal.attr('id', 'attachment-deletion-'+file.unique_text);
```

I was expecting my document to contain both my new cloned object (with id `attachment-deletion-unique_text`) as well as `$('#attachment-deletion');`

but this isn't what I am seeing. I am not calling `remove();` on these selectors to my knowledge, so I am led to believe the modifying the attributes of a `clone()`'d object affects the original as well

but since I thought clone makes a deep copy, this should be happening so something else is wrong. I am modifying id's so maybe this confuses somethings since for a moment there are two objects in the DOM with the same id, maybe?

any insight appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign cloned element to a variable like this -

```
var attachmentDeletePhotoModal = $('#attachment-deletion');
var cloned  = attachmentDeletePhotoModal.clone();
cloned.attr('id', 'attachment-deletion-'+file.unique_text);
```

Comment: I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157801/jquery-insertafter-for-ie8