# jquery insertAfter for ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, append, insertafter

```
        var attachmentDeleteMainModal = $('#attachment-deletion');
        var attachmentDeleteMainModalClone = attachmentDeleteMainModal.clone();
        attachmentDeleteMainModalClone.attr('id', 'attachment-deletion-'+'main');
        attachmentDeleteMainModalClone.insertAfter('#attachment-deletion');
```

This method adds my new selector to the DOM in Chrome, but does not work in ie8, this is all I tested so far

`append` instead of `insertAfter` does not create the desired selector in either browser. But in ie8 it does not create anything at all

what is the solution to this? any insight appreciated

Comment: Also have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with

```
 $('#attachment-deletion').after(attachmentDeleteMainModalClone);
```

Comment: Didn't help for me also

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 I had an exception in **$rows.insertAfter($(elem))** line, so I fixed it with this solution:

```
            var $rows = $("tr", $(parsedXML));
            try {
                $rows.insertAfter($(elem));
            } catch (error) {
                // we got <table><tbody><tr... from the server and need to paste only all <tr> from it after our tr in $(elem)
                var divData = $("table", $(parsedXML));
                var divTmp = document.createElement("div");
                divTmp.innerHTML = divData[0].xml;
                var children = divTmp.firstChild.firstChild;
                var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                var current = children.firstChild;

                while (current) {
                    fragment.appendChild(current.cloneNode(true));
                    current = current.nextSibling;
                }

                elem.parentNode.insertBefore(fragment, elem.nextSibling);
            }
```

Sorry, it is not so clean with ".firstChild.firstChild", but worked for me.
We got `<table><tbody><tr...` from the server and need to paste only all `<tr>` from it after our tr in `$(elem)`